# Approximation of $\sqrt{ x + y } - \sqrt{ x - y }$

Tags: functions, approximation

I've been struggling to try and find a way to approximate the function:

$\sqrt{ x + y } - \sqrt{ x - y }$

I should mention that $y$ is positive and a small number, so that $0<y<<1$.

What I'm hoping for is to approximate this in such a way that, we have roughly:

$\sqrt{ x + y } - \sqrt{ x - y } \approx (1-y)\sqrt{ x + y }$

There may be some numerical factor in front of this. This could very well be absurd, I'm wondering if this can be done at all. It is crucial that I have this factor $\sqrt{ x + y }$ in the approximation.

I've thought about defining a function $\ f(r)=\sqrt{r}$. Then I could write:

$f(x+y)-f(x-y)$ = $f(x+y)-f(x+y-2y)$

i've tried taking a Taylor expansion but my result isn't working out. Does anyone have some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+y$ and $w=\sqrt{z}=\sqrt{ x + y }$. Then

$$
\def\F#1/#2;{\frac{#1}{#2}}
\sqrt{ x + y } - \sqrt{ x - y }
=
\sqrt{z } - \sqrt{ z - 2y }
=
\F y/w;+
\F y^2/2 w^3;+
\F y^3/2 w^5;+
\F 5 y^4/8 w^7;+
\F 7 y^5/8 w^9;+
\F 21 y^6/16 w^{11};+O(y^7)
$$

This expression uses $\sqrt{ x + y }$ and $y$ as required.

Comment: What do you mean by: *This expression uses $\sqrt {x+y}$ and $y$ as required*?

Comment: @EnthusiasticStudent The original question says that it is crucial that the factor $\sqrt{x+y}$ is included. Some of the suggested answers use the variable $x$ rather than $x+y$. Changing the variable to $w$ means that this part of the question is answered. Note also that $y$ is said to be small, so that is the best choice in the expansion to help identify small terms.

Comment: Series adapted from [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+sqrt%28z%29-sqrt%28z-2y%29).

Comment: Not that three terms of this series is by far much worse than 3 terms of a taylor series as presented in other answers. I wonder why this was accepted when its more complex and less accurate?

Answer (score 10):

$$\sqrt{x+y}-\sqrt{x-y}=\frac{(\sqrt{x+y}-\sqrt{x-y})(\sqrt{x+y}+\sqrt{x-y})}{\sqrt{x+y}+\sqrt{x-y}}=\frac{2y}{\sqrt{x+y}+\sqrt{x-y}}\approx\frac{y}{\sqrt{x}}$$
Or, if you want a factor of $\sqrt{x+y}$, you can write it as
$$\sqrt{x+y}-\sqrt{x-y}\approx \frac{y}{x}\sqrt{x+y}.$$

Comment: You could have $\sqrt {x+y}$ in the denominator, since the question seems to want that expression retained.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert $f(y) = \sqrt{x+y}=\sqrt{x-y}$ into a 3rd order taylor series

$$f(y) \approx f(0) + (y-0)\,\left. \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} \right|_{y=0} + 
\dfrac{(y-0)^2}{2}\,\left. \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \right|_{y=0} + 
\dfrac{(y-0)^2}{6}\,\left. \dfrac{\partial^3 f}{\partial y^3} \right|_{y=0}$$

$$ f(y) \approx \dfrac{y}{\sqrt{x}} + \dfrac{y^3}{8 \sqrt{x^5}} $$

Comment: not as fast as you were :-)

Comment: I used a _CAS_ for speed and accuracy. I see you went one up on terms. Well $f \approx \sqrt{x} \left(r+\frac{r^3}{8}+\frac{7r^5}{128}+\frac{33 r^7}{1024}+\frac{715 r^9}{32768} \right)$ with $r=y/x$.

Comment: what is a CAS? (if I may ask)

Comment: Computer Algebra System : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system

Comment: I see, many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use a Taylor's series expansion for $f(y)=\sqrt{ x + y } - \sqrt{ x - y }$:
\begin{align}
f(y)&=\frac{y}{\sqrt x}+\frac{y^3}{8x^{5/2}}+\frac{7y^5}{128x^{9/2}}+O(y^7)\\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Try this one for size:

$$ f(y) \approx \sqrt{x} \left( \arcsin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \right) $$

or

$$ f(y) \approx \sqrt{x} \left( \arcsin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)-\frac{1}{24}\left(\arcsin\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)\right)^3 \right) $$

The last one is almost an exact fit throughtout the range of $y$. I got it by setting $y=x \sin(r)$ and perfoming a taylor expansion on $$f(r)=\sqrt{x} \left( \sqrt{1+\sin(r)}-\sqrt{1-\sin(r)} \right) \\ = \sqrt{x} \left(r-\frac{r^3}{24}\right)$$

See the comparison for yourself at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7Bsqrt%281%2Br%29-sqrt%281-r%29%2C+asin%28r%29-asin%28r%29%5E3%2F24%7D)

<sup>Alternative link to Wolfram, http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ef6ds3l1c74</sup>

[image: pic]